# Is there always a continuous extension of a countable collection of quotient maps, whose domains are a Haussdorff-convergent sequence?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, quotient-spaces

Let $(\mathbf{B},\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space, $(A_{n})$,$(B_{n})$ collections of compact, connected subsets of $\mathbf{B}$ and let $\{q_{n}:A_{n}\to B_{n} : n\geq 1\}$ be a collection of quotient maps (closed, continuous, surjective).

The Hausdorff distance $d_{H}$ is a metric on the collection of closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbf{B}$.
$$
d_{H}(A,B)= \max\left\{   \sup_{b\in B} \|b-A\|   \,,\,   \sup_{a\in A} \|a-B\|   \right\}
$$
where $\|b-A\|=\inf\{\|b-a\| : a\in A\}$ as usual.

If $d_{H}(A_{n},A)\to 0$ and $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}, \ldots, A$ are mutually disjoint:

(Q1) Does this implies the existence of a continuous function 
$$ P:\bigsqcup A_{n} \to \bigsqcup B_{n} $$ 
such that $P_{|A_{n}} = q_{n}$ for every $n\geq 1$?

(Q2) Suppose $P$ exists. Is the Hausdorff limit $A$ contained in the domain, 
   or does $P$ should be extended further?

(Q3) Suppose $P$ had to be extended in its domain to contain $A$,what can we say about $P_{|A}$?

(Q4) If the quotient maps $q_{n}:A_{n} \to B_{n}$ are Lipschitz continuous (or some other type of strong continuity), does that makes any difference?

$\mathbf{New \, questions}$ (20 Jun):  Let $A'=\bigsqcup A_{n}$

I would like to characterize Hausdorff convergence of the sequence ${P(A_{n})}={B_{n}}$.

When $P$ can be extended $\mathtt{continuously}$ to $(A' \sqcup A)$ its known that $d_{H}(A_{n},A) \to 0$ implies $d_{H}(P(A_{n}),P(A))= d_{H}(B_{n},P(A))\to 0$. This continuous extension exists whenever $\{x_{n}\}\subset A'$ converges in $A' \sqcup A$ then $\{P(x_{n})\}$ converges.

Suppose $P$ has not yet been extended to contain $A$ in its domain, and let $q:A\to B$ be a quotient map for some $B\subset \mathbf{B}$, then:

(Q5) Since $A$ and $A'$ are disjoint and define a locally finite family: There a continuous extension of $P$ and $q$? What is happening here?

(Q6) If all the quotient are Lipschitz, i.e. $\|q_{n}(x)\| \leq \|x\|$ for every $x\in A_{n}$. Does convergence of a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$, and therefore boundedness of $\{P(x_{n})\}$, implies some sort of Hausdorff convergence for the sequence $P(A_{n})=B_{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Yes. Put $A’=\bigsqcup A_{n}$. The family $\{A_n\}$ is locally finite in $A’$. Indeed, let $x\in A’$ be an arbitrary point. Since $x\not\in A$ and the set $A$ is closed, $\varepsilon=\|x-A\|/2>0$. Since the sequence $\{A_n\}$ converges to $A$, there exists a number $N$ such that $d_H(A_n, A)<\varepsilon$ for each $n>N$. Thus the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of the point $x$ if disjoint from the set $A_n$ for each $n>N$. Now the continuity of the map $P$ follows from [Eng, Prop. 2.1.13]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Q2. Yes, of course, because by definition domain $\bigsqcup A_{n}$ of $P$ is disjoint from $A$. But extension of $P$ to $A$ exists iff for every sequence  $\{x_n\}$ of points of $A’$convergent in  $A’\cup A$ ,  the sequence $\{ P(x_n )\}$ is also convergent (see, for instance, [MR, Lemma 2]. It not always exists. For instance, let $(\mathbf{B},\|\cdot\|)$ be the space $\Bbb R$ endowed with the standard norm, $A_n=\{1/n\}$, $B_n=\{n\}$, and $A=\{0\}$.

Q3. Can you tell more precisely in which properties of $P$ you are interested?

Q4. I guess, no.

*References*

[MR] M. A. Mytrofanov, A. V. Ravsky, *[Approximation of continuous functions on Fréchet spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1814)*, Journal of Mathematical Sciences, **185**:6 (2012), 792--799

[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

Comment: Thank you, your answers where very enlightning and reassured some of my own thoughts.

More than properties about $P$ I'm interested in observing when does Haussdorf convergence is preserved  through mappings

In your example, 1/n ---->n is not Lipschitz, therefore I thought that maybe asking for stronger continuity on the collection of quotient maps could make it possible to extend P.

More specifically, considering the characterization you gave me for extending continuosly P, I  agreggated two more questions concerning these deeper doubts.

Comment: @MarVaz Q5. Local finiteness doesn’t help anymore because $A’$ is not *closed* in $A' \sqcup A$. A counterxample when $P$ and $q$ generate a non-continuous map is, for instance, when $q_n(x)=x$ for all $x$ and $n$, but $q(y)\ne y$ for some $y$.

Comment: Q6 . If $P$ is not extendable to the limit of $\{x_n\}$ then the answer, in general, is negative. Again, in $\Bbb R$ let $A_n=\{1+1/n\}$, $B_n=\{(-1)^n\}$, and $A=\{1\}$.